# Substring exists in string in C

Tags: c, string, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[80] = "downtown", str2[20] = "town";
    
    int len1 = 0, len2 = 0, i, j, count;

    len1 = strlen(str1);
    len2 = strlen(str2);

    for (i = 0; i <= len1 - len2; i++) { 
        for (j = i; j < i + len2; j++) {
            count = 1;
            if (str1[j] != str2[j - i]) {
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        printf("True");
    } else {
        printf("False");
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm trying to solve this one without using string functions apart from `strlen()` which can be replaced with a simple `while` loop. Is there any other way of checking for consecutive characters like firstly checking if the character is in the string, and if the `i` index is in the next position and not randomly in the string.

Comment: Why do you want another method?

Comment: @klutt I remember solving a similar problem but with integers like 500 is in 1500 and remember it being simpler than this one.

Comment: Start by looking for the first character in the sub-string. If you find a match, look at the next character of both strings. If the second character doesn't match, continue searching for the first character in the sub-string, otherwise continue to match the sub-string.

Comment: You may find some alternative at [String-searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm) interesting.

Comment: You could also find some `strstr` implementations, as that seems to be the function you're trying to reimplement.

Comment: What is the returned pointer supposed to point at? The start of the found substring in `str`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very clean way to do it using a function. It assumes that both `str` and `sub` are proper C-strings and returns a pointer to first match and `NULL` if no match.

```
char *substr(const char *str, const char *sub) {
    if (!*sub)
        return str; // Empty string is substring of all strings

    while (*str) {
        const char *sub1 = sub;
        const char *str1 = str;
        while (*str1++ == *sub1++) {
            if (!*sub1)
                return (char *)str;
        }
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This function is identical to the standard function `strstr()`, present in the C Standard library and declared in `<string.h>`.

Comment: I'm not that comfortable with pointers, but seems way simpler than mine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @klutt oh I thought it was for *a. Just an ignorant question: Why is this line needed :char *tmp = sub? Can't we just use *sub instead of *tmp?

Comment: @klutt ohhh got it. Thanks!

Comment: Try `printf("%p\n", substr("ababc", "abc"));`.

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems in the posted code:

- `count` is uninitialized and only set if the inner loop is reached, which will not be the case if `len1 < len2`. `count` should be intialized to `0` to handle this case properly. `found` would be a more informative name for this variable.
- Furthermore, the statement `count = 1;` should be moved before the inner loop to handle the case of an empty substring.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[] = "downtown", str2[] = "town";
    int found = 0;
    size_t len1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(str2);

    if (len1 >= len2) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= len1 - len2; i++) { 
            found = 1;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
                if (str1[i + j] != str2[j]) {
                    found = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        printf("True\n");
    } else {
        printf("False\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also argue that `count` is a bad name since it is used as a boolean

Comment: Congratulations on 100k!

Comment: @klutt: I agree! answer amended.

Answer (score 1):

I did not readily see OP's error.  See [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816466/2410359).

Minor: Use `size_t i`, not `int` to cope with *long* strings.

`strlen(str1)` runs down the entire string, even when not needed, so that is avoided.

---

Alternative:

Fixed a faulty case in [@klutt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816408/2410359) otherwise good answer.

Added `const` for greater application.

Return beginning of match on success.

Simplified and test harness added.

I like the [`needle` in a `haystack` identifiers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needle_in_a_haystack)

```
char* substr3(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
  while (*haystack) {
    const char *htmp = haystack;
    const char *ntmp = needle;
    while (*htmp == *ntmp && *htmp) {
      htmp++;
      ntmp++;
    }
    if (!*ntmp) {
      return (char*) haystack;  // Beginning of match
    }
    haystack++;
  }

  return *needle ? NULL : (char *) haystack;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n", substr3("ababc", "abc"));
  printf("%s\n", substr3("abc", "abc"));
  printf("%s\n", substr3("abd", "ab"));
  printf("%s\n", substr3("abc", ""));
  printf("%s\n", substr3("", ""));

  printf("%p\n", substr3("a", "abc"));
  printf("%p\n", substr3("aba", "abc"));
  printf("%p\n", substr3("x", "ab"));
  printf("%p\n", substr3("aaa", "ab"));
  return 0;
}
```

**Some tighter code**

```
char* substr4(const char *haystack, const char *needle) {
  do {
    const char *htmp = haystack;
    const char *ntmp = needle;
    while (*htmp == *ntmp && *ntmp) {
      htmp++;
      ntmp++;
    }
    if (!*ntmp) {
      return (char*) haystack;  // Beginning of match
    }
  } while (*haystack++);

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I usually frown upon `do`/`while` loops, but in this case it seems OK and changing the inner loop to a `do`/`while` loop would even save a redundant test :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple && naive:

---

```
char *substr2(char *str, char *sub) {

if (!*sub) return str; // not needed: see the generated code.

for(; *str; str++) {
        size_t pos;
        for(pos=0; str[pos] ; pos++) {
                if (str[pos] != sub[pos]) break;
                }
        if (!sub[pos]) return str;
        }
return NULL;
}
```

---

Generally:

- if you don't try to outsmart the compiler: you win.
- fewer variables: you win
- fewer conditions inside the loop: win
- try to be smart: you'll lose
- when all else fails: use [KMP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) or [BM](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boyer-moore-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) search